# Store object created by gson in greenDao

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

**Issue:** I'm not able to insert a gson created object without id into the database using greenDao

**Setup GreenDao**

My web service returns an output like this

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Cleese",
        dateOfBirth: -952473600,
        profession: {
            name: "Actor",
            description: "TV show entertainer"
        }
    }
]
```

`Gson` turns this into a `Person` object that has a `Profession` object. These classes where generated using the `GreenDao Generator`.

```
Schema schema = new Schema(SCHEMA_VERSION, "com.example.dao");

Entity profession = schema.addEntity("Profession");
profession.addIdProperty().autoincrement().notNull();
profession.addStringProperty("name");
profession.addStringProperty("description");

Entity person = schema.addEntity("Person");
person.addIdProperty();
person.addStringProperty("firstName");
person.addStringProperty("lastName");
person.addDateProperty("dateOfBirth");
Property professionProperty = person.addLongProperty("profession_id").getProperty();
person.addToOne(profession, professionProperty);

new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "my/path/java");
```

**Insert issue:**

Now I'm trying to insert the created `Person` object and its `Profession` object like this:

```
DaoMaster master = new DaoMaster(devOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase());
    DaoSession session = master.newSession();
    PersonDao personDao = session.getPersonDao();
    List<Person> people = myWebServiceResponse.getPeople();
    ProfessionDao professionDao = session.getProfessionDao();
    personDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(people);
    for (Person person : people) {
        try {
            professionDao.insertInTx(person.getProfession());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Issue on insert: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The `person.getProfession()` throws this exception: *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.example.dao.Profession.getId()' on a null object reference*

If I turn things around, by inserting the `Profession` first and then the `Person` objects, it throws *Entity is detached from DAO context* on the same `person.getProfession()` call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that GreenDao and Gson are not a friendly couple. This is because in GreenDao, all the entities must be inserted before the object construction.

In this case, Profession is not a field, it's a relation, so when you do person.getProfession() you are retrieving this value from the Profession table, not from the Person object. You should insert both Person and Profession objects and establish their relation afterwards.

It's really an inconvenient that this two tools doesn't work well together, but as far as I know, it's how it works.